# Verot class.upload.php uploading big files

Tags: php, file-upload, filesize

I use an upload form to upload images. Small image like < 4mb will work. 
But if I upload an image with a file size like 5.7MB, it doesn't do anything. It just doesn't upload the file. I have searched a lot but I couldn't figure it out. I think the problem has to deal with this code:

```
case 'png':
                        if (!function_exists('imagecreatefrompng')) {
                            $this->processed = false;
                            $this->error = $this->translate('no_create_support', array('PNG'));
                        } else {
                            echo $this->file_src_pathname;
                            echo $this->log;
                            echo $this->error;
                            echo $image_src = @imagecreatefrompng($this->file_src_pathname);
                            if (!$image_src) {
                                $this->processed = false;
                                $this->error = $this->translate('create_error', array('PNG'));
                            } else {
                                $this->log .= '- source image is PNG<br />';
                            }
                        }
                        break;
```

The @imagecreatefrompng($this->file_src_pathname) function is that piece of code where my code breaks. It doesn't output anything after that code, except when I comment it out. I have already changed my memory limit to 256M and the file upload to 64M. The file name is set. I have no idea why it only breaks my code when it has to deal with big files. Do any of you guys have an idea?

The code on the file upload page is:

//form processing

include('../includes/class.upload.php');

```
    $files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['my_field'] as $k => $l) {
    foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files)) 
            $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
}

foreach ($files as $file) {
if(!empty($file)){

$handle = new Upload($file, 'nl_NL');

            if (!file_exists("../classified_images/$adid")) 
    mkdir("../classified_images/$adid", 0777); 

        $tag_code_p = generatePassword(25);

        if ($handle->uploaded) {
        $oriname = $handle->file_src_name;
        $handle->mime_magic_check = true;
        $handle->allowed = array('image/*');
        $handle->image_convert = 'jpg';
        $newname = $adid."_big_".$tag_code_p;
        $handle->file_new_name_body   = $newname;
        $handle->image_resize          = true;          
        $handle->image_ratio_fill      = true;
        $handle->image_y               = 600;
        $handle->image_x               = 800;
        $handle->image_background_color = '#FFFFFF';
```

//           // now, we start the upload 'process'. That is, to copy the uploaded file
  //           // from its temporary location to the wanted location
  //           // It could be something like $handle->Process('/home/www/my_uploads/');
            $handle->Process("../classified_images/");

```
        // we check if everything went OK
        if ($handle->processed) {

        $handle->image_convert = 'jpg';
        $newnamesmall =$adid."_small_".$tag_code_p;
        $handle->file_new_name_body   = $newnamesmall;
        $handle->image_resize          = true;          
        $handle->image_ratio_fill      = true;
        $handle->image_y               = 94;
        $handle->image_x               = 125;
        $handle->image_background_color = '#FFFFFF';

        // now, we start the upload 'process'. That is, to copy the uploaded file
        // from its temporary location to the wanted location
        // It could be something like $handle->Process('/home/www/my_uploads/');
        $handle->Process("../classified_images/");

        $handle->clean();
                //inserten in database
    $sql_foto_insert = "insert into  photos 
                ( adid,  photosmall,  photo)
                values
                ('$adid', '$newnamesmall.jpg','$newname.jpg')";
    $foto_result = mysql_query($sql_foto_insert);  

            // everything was fine !
            //$msg .= $oriname.' '.LANG_FOTOS_SAVED.'<br />';
            $allok = 1;

        } else {
            // one error occured
            $msg .= $handle->error . '<br />';
        }

    }
```

Comment: could be a few things. If you're on your own machine and have made changes to any system files, did you restart all services after? Or, if you're trying to store an image as a BLOB, then it may be too small, try MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB.  See if anything comes of using http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by configuration issues. Since this happens for files > certain size, I feel it can be related to php ini settings.

Check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php ini settings. These could be set to 4MB. You can increase these values to make it work.

If you are in a shared hosting environment where you cannot edit php ini, you can add them to `.htaccess` file like so:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 7M
php_value post_max_size 7M
```

Also you should remove the `@` from your function to see what the error is. Suppressing errors by adding `@` is a bad idea while developing/debugging.

Additionally, if you are in a local machine or own dev server, open the `apache error_log` and check the last few lines to see what the error is. If you are on a third party server, most control panels provide an interface to view the error log.

Comment: OP states: *"I have already changed my memory limit to 256M and the file upload to 64M."*

Comment: @Fred-ii- `post_max_size` can still be relevant